# How to distinguish unsigned int from uint32_t

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to find all code which is using as `size` other than `uint32_t`.
I've made my custom `SizeStub` type with `uint32_t` inside. And started code replace. To avoid false alerts on code where I already have `uint32_t` I've added next operators:

```
template <typename T>
SizeStub& operator += (const T& in)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, decltype(_value)>::value, "NOT SAME");
    this->_value += in;
    return *this;
}
```

Also binary operators, etc.

Everything is great. I have compile time alerts for all types except `uin32_t` and ... `unsigned int`.
So. How to distinguish `unsigned int` which is not fixed size?

gcc version 4.8.2

P.S. The plan is to replace all `SizeStub` usage when I'll fix all compile time alerts onto `uint32_t`.

Comment: on your platform, a uint32_t *IS* an unsigned int. it's the same type.

Comment: I know this @RichardHodges

Comment: I'd suggest switch to a 64-bit platform for a while. Usually all implicit type conversions break in these conditions.

Comment: Using libtool from clang may help, but requires to write code to search in AST `unsigned int`.

Comment: if your only goal is to clean up the current code to get rid of all uses of `unsigned int`, why not simply perform a global search for it ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker because the task is not to replace ALL `unsigned int` usage in code but only related to concrete methods. Which could be called using function pointers also. Find all code will give me tons of wrong results.

Comment: @denys : if the number of false positives will be high, that's indeed not a very workable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint32_t` is (afaik always) a typedef to the unsigned 32 bit integer type available on the platform you compile for.

Do in your case `uint32_t` is defined via `typedef unsigned int  uint32_t;`

So `uint32_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`, just using another name.

**EDIT:** Accidently submitted before I was done...

You might have some possibilities on how to achieve your goal:

1. You could switch to a platform where `uint32_t` isn't the same type as `unsigned int`. This might work, yet you need to be careful. For example if you are using MSVC as compiler `unsigned int` is always a 32 bit unsigned integer type - regardless of compiling for 32 or 64 bit.
2. You could try to redefine `uint32_t` to a distinct type that can handle (assign, cast, ...) values that are of type `unsigned int`. This would make you aware of uneqal cases... Yet it might complex to find the correct position in code to redefine `uint32_t` so your compiler will fail on all cases you want it to fail.
3. In addition to 2: You could temporarly(!) alter the original typedef. Maybe you want to set up a seperate build environment to do this, so your "real" build environment isn't affected by it.

Maybe someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `unsigned int` is 32 bits, then it and `uint32_t` are the *same type*. You can't differentiate between one type.

Since `uint32_t` is only a type alias, this is comparable to `typedef x y` where you can't differentiate between `x` and `y`.